# Pragma solidity error while trying to compile contract with truffle

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, pragma, cryptocurrency

I'm hoping one of you guys can help me out with what I'm doing wrong :). I get this error every time I try to compile with truffle

```
Truffle v5.3.9 (core: 5.3.9)
Node v14.17.0
PS C:\Users\andre\Desktop\****> cd .\core\
PS C:\Users\andre\Desktop\****\core> truffle migrate --reset --network binanceTestnet

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Migration.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\PancakeERC20.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\PancakeFactory.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\PancakePair.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Token1.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Token2.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IERC20.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IPancakeCallee.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IPancakeERC20.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IPancakeFactory.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IPancakePair.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\libraries\Math.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\libraries\SafeMath.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\libraries\UQ112x112.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\test\ERC20.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\PancakeERC20.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\PancakePair.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IERC20.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IPancakeCallee.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IPancakeERC20.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IPancakeFactory.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IPancakePair.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\libraries\Math.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\libraries\SafeMath.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\libraries\UQ112x112.sol
> Compiling .\node_modules\@openzeppelin\contracts\GSN\Context.sol
> Compiling .\node_modules\@openzeppelin\contracts\math\SafeMath.sol
> Compiling .\node_modules\@openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC20\ERC20.sol
> Compiling .\node_modules\@openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC20\ERC20Detailed.sol
> Compiling .\node_modules\@openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC20\IERC20.sol

/C/Users/andre/Desktop/****/core/contracts/Token1.sol:1:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
��pragma solidity =0.5.16;
^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.3.9 (core: 5.3.9)
Node v14.17.0
PS C:\Users\andre\Desktop\****\core>
```

and here is the Token1.sol file:

```
pragma solidity =0.5.16;

import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token1 is ERC20Detailed, ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20Detailed('Token 1', 'TK1', 18) public {}
}
```

I hope this makes any sense :) I have had some issues with importing @openzeppelin for some reason import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol" does not work for me but if I add "../node_modules/" in front it fixes the problem. or maybe it does I am not sure if that's the reason my compile is giving me error :).

Comment: It seems like there are some special characters in front of your pragma statement: ��pragma solidity =0.5.16; Try removing those characters because that's what the compiler doesn't recognize

Comment: yeah that was what I was thinking too but there isn't anything in front of it its the beginning of the code